# Is it possible to do mixed ANOVA in statsmodels?

Tags: anova, interpretation, statsmodels

I'm analyzing an experiment where I have groups of people labeled `y` and `o` and all participants view three visualizations which are abstract, mixed or realistic and some `value` is calculated for each view. This results in the following long format:

```
    Subject Group   Vis         value
0   0       y       abstract    264.965909
1   1       y       abstract    389.299465
2   2       y       abstract    249.369811
3   3       y       abstract    456.355828
4   4       o       abstract    277.608696
... ...     ...     ...         ...
238 76      o       realistic   382.129353
239 77      y       realistic   401.300000
240 78      o       realistic   279.120805
241 79      o       realistic   274.628378
242 80      y       realistic   292.848485
```

(the unlabeled very first column is just the pandas Data Frame index). Given this experiment design, there are two factors `Group`  and `Vis`ualization. Therefore to analyze this with ANOVA, a two-way mixed ANOVA is required because the group membership is mutually exclusive. I'm did this in Python using the pingouin package:

```
pg.mixed_anova(
    dv="value",
    data=df_melt,
    between="Group", within="Vis",
    subject="Subject"
).round(3)

Source       SS         DF1 DF2 MS          F       p-unc   np2     eps
Group        132084.611 1   79  132084.611  13.470  0.000   0.146   NaN
Vis          26109.383  2   158 13054.691   7.942   0.001   0.091   0.951
Interaction  56162.237  2   158 28081.118   17.083  0.000   0.178   NaN
```

and then tried to confirm the results using `statsmodels`:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
model = ols('value ~ C(Group) + C(Vis) + C(Group):C(Vis)', data=df_melt).fit()
sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=2)
```

The calculated Sum of Squares seem to be the same but the calculated p-values are not the same. Am I correct in concluding that `statsmodels` is not doing a mixed ANOVA?